# Cannot grant network service user rights to read image files

Tags: windows-7, iis, file-permissions

I have a website that runs, locally, by default as Network Service. This site cannot serve out images, this always results in an "access denied". I've used procmon to establish this is happening at the file system level.

There's a couple of elements of this that I don't understand. Firstly a .gif can be in the same folder, with the same permissions, as a .css file and the .css can be read, but the .gif can't. If I give the network service account "Full Control" rights over the whole folder tree, it still can't serve the image.

What I assume is important is that this doesn't only affect the Network Service account. In fact the only user that can run the site and serve images is my windows admin account. Even another admin user can't seem to serve them (regardless of where on the disk the site is located). Again, any of the users can serve the .css but not the .gif.

The attached image shows procmon demonstrating the css / gif difference.
[image: Procmon access messages]

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some files (for unknown reasons) were encrypted on disk, and others not. Therefore whatever the permissions, you had to be the main windows user to read them...